# Stream operator and abstract class

Tags: c++

Anyone tell me how to call stream `>>` operator for 2D object of abstract class pointer in main.

I want to assign the value to private members of all derived classes from base class. Is it possible ? How?

```cpp
istream & operator>>(istream& input,empolye  &p)
{
    cout << "Enter department type:";
    input >> p.type;
    cout << "Enter available bed:";
    input >> p.avilable_bed;
    cout << "Enter type of empolye ";
    input >> p.empolye_type;
    cout << "Enter empolye name";
    input >> p.name;
    cout << "Enter age";
    input >> p.age;
    cout << "Enter date of join";
    input >> p.dateOfjoin;
}
```

I hope everyone is able to get my question.
Thanks everyone.

Comment: yes, but type, name etc will need to be functions that deliver a reference to the data

Comment: Thanks Mr.Richard

Comment: You mean derived classes have further `private` members in addition to those in `employee`, and a call like `std::cin >> my_employee;` should allow the user to enter values for them?

Comment: exactly Christian Hack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep all operator overloading in the base class (directly or semantically via `friend`). Do *not* think about making the operator virtual. Have the implementation of your operator call a **private virtual** member function on the `employee` object; that function acts as a hook which a derived class can override to add more input operations.

The basic idea behind such an approach, which separates the public interface of a class from the customisation points accessible to derived classes, is related to the [Non-Virtual Interface Idiom](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm) or the Template Method design pattern.

Here is an example; have a close look at the `ReadMore` function, which does nothing in the base class but which does something in the derived class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class employee
{
public:
    virtual ~employee() {}

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, employee &p)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter department type: ";
        input >> p.type;
        std::cout << "Enter available bed: ";
        input >> p.available_bed;
        std::cout << "Enter type of employee: ";
        input >> p.employee_type;
        std::cout << "Enter employee name: ";
        input >> p.name;
        std::cout << "Enter age: ";
        input >> p.age;
        std::cout << "Enter date of join: ";
        input >> p.date_of_join;
        p.ReadMore(input);
        return input;
    }

private:
    virtual void ReadMore(std::istream&) {}

    int type;
    int available_bed;
    int employee_type;
    std::string name;
    int age;
    int date_of_join;
};

class special_employee : public employee
{
private:
    void ReadMore(std::istream& input) override
    {
        std::cout << "Enter extra data: ";
        input >> extra_data;
    }

    int extra_data;

};

int main()
{
    special_employee my_special_employee;
    employee& my_employee = my_special_employee;
    std::cin >> my_employee;
}
```

This approach can become somewhat unwieldy if `special_employee` is again inherited from, because then you'd have to add another hook function. However, class hierarchies with more than two levels in the business logic of your application are often bad design anyway, and usually an indicator that you should switch to a composition-based design.

Comment: Thanks ... Christian Hackl

Comment: Is this technique work for top to bottom or we can also able to jump for specfic class

Comment: @Nouman: Are you familiar with virtual functions? If not, you should learn them with much simpler examples...

Comment: Thanks @Christian Hack